# Recolour entire terminal in C#

Tags: c#, windows, console

In a program I am writing, I want the entire console background to turn blue when there is an error. In Python or C this is easily achieved with `os.system("color 17")`. How can I do this in C#?

The code I have been trying seems to execute the command in a different window and has no effect on the main one.

```
public static int system(String command)
        {
            Process cmd = new Process();
            cmd.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
            cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
            cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            cmd.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
            cmd.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            cmd.Start();

            cmd.StandardInput.WriteLine(command);
            cmd.StandardInput.Flush();
            cmd.StandardInput.Close();
            cmd.WaitForExit();
            Console.WriteLine(cmd.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd());
            return cmd.ExitCode;
        }
```

and then calling this with `system("color 17")`

I have tried flipping some of the cmd.StartInfo arguments but that just seems to crash the program.

I am using Microsoft .NET 6.0 on Windows 11 using Visual Studio 2022 if that helps at all

Comment: To clarify: you state that launching cmd.exe (e.g. using `os.system("cmd")` or `subprocess.run(["cmd"])`) from Python, you can change the background color using `os.system("color 17")`? If that's not the case, you're not comparing like for like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use external applications, this isn't the 80s. Especially for something as trivial as console buffer manipulation.

.Net actually comes with `Console.BackgroundColor` and `Console.ForegroundColor` built-in to set the character attributes for new characters, so all that's missing is changing existing characters in the buffer to the required attributes (which is what `color` does). The function for that is `FillConsoleOutputAttribute`.

So putting it together, the code to achieve what you wish is simply:

```
public static void Main()
{
    var stdout = GetStdHandle(-11);
    FillConsoleOutputAttribute(stdout,
        CharAttributes.BACKGROUND_BLUE | CharAttributes.FOREGROUND_BLUE | CharAttributes.FOREGROUND_RED | CharAttributes.FOREGROUND_GREEN,
        (uint)(Console.BufferWidth * Console.BufferHeight), new(), out var _);

    Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkBlue;
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Gray;
}
```

With a couple of P/Invoke definitions:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct COORD
{
    public short X;
    public short Y;
}

enum CharAttributes : ushort
{
    None = 0x0000,
    FOREGROUND_BLUE = 0x0001,
    FOREGROUND_GREEN = 0x0002,
    FOREGROUND_RED = 0x0004,
    FOREGROUND_INTENSITY = 0x0008,
    BACKGROUND_BLUE = 0x0010,
    BACKGROUND_GREEN = 0x0020,
    BACKGROUND_RED = 0x0040,
    BACKGROUND_INTENSITY = 0x0080,

    COMMON_LVB_LEADING_BYTE = 0x0100,
    COMMON_LVB_TRAILING_BYTE = 0x0200,
    COMMON_LVB_GRID_HORIZONTAL = 0x0400,
    COMMON_LVB_GRID_LVERTICAL = 0x0800,
    COMMON_LVB_GRID_RVERTICAL = 0x1000,
    COMMON_LVB_REVERSE_VIDEO = 0x4000,
    COMMON_LVB_UNDERSCORE = 0x8000,
}

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern bool FillConsoleOutputAttribute(IntPtr hConsoleOutput, CharAttributes wAttribute, uint nLength, COORD dwWriteCoord, out uint lpNumberOfAttrsWritten);

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern IntPtr GetStdHandle(int nStdHandle);
```